# How can I make Siri redirect routing requests into my navigation app?

Tags: ios, routes, siri, map-directions

The iOS app I'm working on is correctly configured as a routing app according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html). It is displayed in the Apple Maps' *Routing Apps* section and receives `MKDirectionsRequest` in its `application:openURL:options:` when a user asks the Maps app for directions and chooses my app.

I want the user to be able to ask Siri invoke navigation in my app by saying something like "Start navigation in *my_app_name* to *some_address*".

What I observe is such thing is possible with e.g. Google Maps, Waze and several other apps:

[image]

However, for many routing apps on my device (including the one I'm developing) it does not work:

[image]

Is it possible to make it work for my app?

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the feature still exists in the form of ad hoc integrations with some specific apps and doesn't expose any public API in iOS SDK.

First time it was [briefly mentioned](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/101/?time=3557) in WWDC 2019 keynote and has never received any more detail in other sessions or developer documentation since then.

WWDC20 is coming in June, so we can of course look for updates this year — and if there are none you should still be able to "engage with Apple engineers" directly, as they mention on the website.